# Accessing Ubuntu via Remote Desktop

Tags: virtualization, remote-desktop, kvm-virtualization

More specifically the way it looks via Remote Desktop.

I've tinkered with Ubuntu for a long time, but wanted to try something new. 
I have a Scale HC3 cluster (KVM/qemu) and have Ubuntu installed in a VM and it looks like it would on a physical PC except it is limited to 800x600. On the VM I installed xrdp and accessed it from Remote Desktop. But it is missing the launcher and the looks isn't exactly the same.
Any tips on viewing Ubuntu normally via Remote Desktop? Thanks

On the Scale system I see....
[image: On the Scale system I see....]

In RDP I see...

[image]

...then...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a know situation and luckily, there is a solution...If you check out this post (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12155, you will have a nice little explanation on what to do to get the same look n feel within your remote session....

In a few words, you will need to install the gnome tweak software in your Ubuntu and using the tool, you will be able to enable the launcher and the theme to be used...

You have even more luck as the blog is also providing a script that can help automating this process...Have a look at this post ([http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12198])[2](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12198). The script is set to version 0.3 and allows you to configure automatically the look n feel within the remote session

Finally note, that this is not the last version of the script, a more recent version is also available and version number is set to 0.5.

Hope this is helpful 
Till next time 
See ya